# JqueryTrigger / click anchor tag click from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, click, anchor

I created a variable that pulls the value from a div.  This works.

```
<input type="text" id="myDiv" class="input"> FOO </input>

<script>
var whatsInMyDiv = $('#myDiv').val();
</script>
```

That value will match the text of any one of my list items below.

```
<li><a href="#FOO" value="#FOO">FOO</a></li>
<li><a href="#BAR" value="#BAR">BAR</a></li>
```

How do I trigger the 'clicking' of the correct anchor tag from my dynamic variable?

Something like this, which doesn't work obviously:

```
$(whatsInMyDiv).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give an ID selector with #

```
$("#" + whatsInMyDiv).click()
```

And add those ids to your a elements maybe instead of useless value.

```
<li><a href="#FOO" id ="FOO">FOO</a></li>
<li><a href="#BAR" id ="BAR">BAR</a></li>
```

Or if you really need to leave html like it is use another selector:

```
$("a[value='#" + whatsInMyDiv + "']").click()
```